# Modal dialog to open on site, not per link

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have a site collection with several sub-site collections/sub-sites where some of the 'New Item' links open in a modal dialog, and some don't. The behavior to open in a modal dialog is, from what I understand, default SP2010 settings. However, a couple of custom solutions has given a very inconsistent experience.

Is there a C# or configuration solution that would force modal dialogs on just New Items at a scope bigger than just per link?

Comment: Open in modal dialog is list settings. See "List Settings"->"Advanced Settings"->"Open in popup".

Comment: Will that apply to the entire site for every instance of 'Add New Item'?

Comment: If you change the List settings, it will apply only to the list in question.

Comment: There is no OOTB way to apply this setting to entire site. You could think of some options using javascript if you have custom master page though.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really looking for a OOTB solution, just a solution in general. I managed to fenagle a script to do it for me in the Master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNewItemFix() {
        $(".ms-addnew").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is("a")) {
                var gReference = $(this).attr("href");
                var options = {
                    title: "New Item",
                    url: gReference
                };
                $(this).attr("onclick", "javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title: 'New Item',url:'" + gReference + "'}); return false;");
            }
        });
    }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("addNewItemFix");
</script>
```

This will look for every instance of the class `.ms-addnew`, which SP2010 puts on both the TD and the Anchor tags. For each `.ms-addnew`, it'll look just for the anchors, grab the href attribute then reformat it to do a modal dialog instead.

Works like a charm, though make sure that `core.js` or `init.js` is called **BEFORE** you put this script in, since it uses the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` method.

This script is tested and should work as a copy/paste.